# How to use regex add brackets to the beginning and end of the first line in a field of text?

Tags: regex, replace

I have the following field of text:

```
The blue bus drove by

Key features:
It is red in color
It is smaller than a dog
It is bigger than a cat
```

But I need brackets around the first line of the text like below:

```
[The blue bus drove by]

Key features:
It is red in color
It is smaller than a dog
It is bigger than a cat
```

I have to do this for multiple fields of text that do not have matching features (other than the first line of every sample is bolded so maybe if there is a way to add brackets before and after all bolded lines?).

Is there anyway to use regex to add brackets to only the first line of the field?

I have tried the following, which adds a bracket to the beginning of the line.

Find: `^\A(.*)$`
Replace: `[$1`

I have tried the following, but it adds a bracket to the end of the entire text field, rather than the first line.

Find: `^(.*)$\z`
Replace: `$1]`

So my field ends up looking like

```
[The blue bus drove by

Key features:
It is red in color
It is smaller than a dog
It is bigger than a cat]
```

Comment: Are you using a programming language? SO is for programming questions.

Comment: If there are multiple fields, how do you define where each field starts and ends?

Comment: Your first regex looks fine; just change the replacement to `[$1]`.

Comment: Perhaps match 2 newlines at the end, and use those in the replacement. `^(.*)\n\n` https://regex101.com/r/9HgK0D/1

Answer (score 0):

pattern

```
^([\S ]+)(\r?\n)
```

replacement

```
[$1]$2
```

test link: https://regex101.com/r/Fm3TUQ/2